# Predicate Logic: Exists-proof

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I've entered my proof on [this website](https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) and I don't understand why following proof isn't okay.

As you can see, the proof checker tells me that I've used the rule for $\exists$ in a wrong way. Is this just a made a small spelling/definition mistake or am I using the rule entirely wrong?

As far as I'm aware I can conclude $\exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(s)$ from the subproof via Exist-Elimination if i've written the same thing inside of the subproof.

[image]

Comment: It seems that you're switching the variable from consequent to antecedent without giving good reason. Perhaps you should use universal instantiation to derive $Pt$

Comment: But I can choose a fresh variable after the $\forall$-Elimination. So deriving Pt is a valid thing to do, isn't it? Or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: $Pt$ is valid. The problem is that the original quantifier applies to the consequent of the conditional (Q is the consequent of $P \to Q$). However, you "switch" it to the antecedent (P is the antecedent of $P \to Q$) without giving a reason.

Comment: Okay, i got it. Is there any good way to fix this? Like how can I make the quantifier applying to the antecent?

Comment: You could probably just use universal instantiation to show that $Pt$ is true.

Comment: I think that argument is invalid. It is not possible to prove it.

Comment: Proof checker complains because the name you used to apply *Existential Elimination* on line 6, namely _s_, already appears in an undischarged assumption (line 4). It is a restriction imposed by this rule.

Comment: As a counter example, consider: Domain $\{0,1\}$ and truth sets $P: \{0,1\}$, $Q: \{1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your existential elimination attempt is that the witness variable, $s$, occurs free in the conclusion line 5: $\exists x~(Px\to Qs)$.

---

The argument as a whole is invalid.

- $\forall x~\exists y~(Px\to Qy)$ and $\forall x~Px$ are satisfiable exactly when *everything* satisfies $P$ and *something* satisfies $Q$.
- However, given that, the conclusion $\forall y~\exists x~(Px\to Qy)$ *may* be *unsatisfied* when *something else* does not satisfy $Q$.
- Therefore the premises do not logically entail the conclusion you wish.